# Letting the user select whether to run a program again?

Tags: java

I am apologise for the obscurity of this question - I could not figure out another way to word it. I was tasked with building a program that counts the number of vowels in a phrase, outputs this number to the user, then asks the user if they would like to repeat the program. It is supposed to ask the user to press '1' to start the program again, and any other number to exit. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner UserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner UserExit = new Scanner(System.in);
      int UserDecision;
      String Choice;

      String Phrase;
      int VowelCount = 0;
      System.out.println(" This programme will count the number of vowels in it. \nThis includes a, e, i, o and u, "
              + "but excludes 'y'. Please enter a phrase below and hit 'enter' when done.");
      Phrase = UserInput.nextLine();
    String Phrase2 = Phrase.toLowerCase();
      boolean Exit = false;
      for(int initial = 0; initial < Phrase2.length() && Exit == false; initial ++)
      {
          if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'a')
          {
              VowelCount++;
          }
          else if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'e')
          {
              VowelCount++;
          }
          else if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'i')
          {
              VowelCount++;
          }
          else if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'o')
          {
              VowelCount++;
          }
          else if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'u')
          {
              VowelCount++;
          }

          System.out.println("There are " +VowelCount+ " vowel(s) in your phrase. Please press '1' to run the programme again\n"
                  + "or any other number to exit.");
          Choice = UserExit.nextLine();
           UserDecision = Integer.parseInt(Choice);
         if (UserDecision != 1)
         {
              Exit = true;
          }

      }
    }
}
```

The 'vowel counter' in the program works perfectly - I cannot figure out how to get the loop to 'reset' or 'repeat' at the user's request, however. I was considering creating a second do-while loop, but I am not sure if this is the way to go...?

Comment: Put another loop around your current code.

Comment: You definitely don't want to create *two* `Scanner` objects. There's only one user.

Comment: Notation comment: Variable names should start with lower case letters (e.g. `vowelCount` instead of `VowelCount`). Class names do start with upper case letters. Reserve all-caps for static variables

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the game logic code inside a `do... while()` loop:

```
// ...
userDecision = 0;
do {
    // Code goes here
} while(userDecision == 1)
// ...
```

or, if you prefer, use a `while()` loop:

```
// ...
boolean exit = false;
while(!exit) {
    // Code goes here
    exit = (userExit.nextInt() != 1);
}
// ...
```

---

As I posted in my comment, you should use a notation convention:

- Variables start with lower case letters (I personally recommend you use camelCase)
- Class names start with upper case letters (again, I personally recommend you use CamelCase)
- Reserve all-caps for static variables

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap all your main game logic into a while(true) and just break if the exit command is met

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner UserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
          Scanner UserExit = new Scanner(System.in);
          int UserDecision;
          String Choice;

          String Phrase;
    while(true){
          int VowelCount = 0;
          System.out.println(" This programme will count the number of vowels in it. \nThis includes a, e, i, o and u, "
                  + "but excludes 'y'. Please enter a phrase below and hit 'enter' when done.");
          Phrase = UserInput.nextLine();
        String Phrase2 = Phrase.toLowerCase();
          boolean Exit = false;
          for(int initial = 0; initial < Phrase2.length() && Exit == false; initial ++)
          {
              if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'a')
              {
                  VowelCount++;
              }
              else if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'e')
              {
                  VowelCount++;
              }
              else if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'i')
              {
                  VowelCount++;
              }
              else if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'o')
              {
                  VowelCount++;
              }
              else if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'u')
              {
                  VowelCount++;
              }

              System.out.println("There are " +VowelCount+ " vowel(s) in your phrase. Please press '1' to run the programme again\n"
                      + "or any other number to exit.");
              Choice = UserExit.nextLine();
               UserDecision = Integer.parseInt(Choice);
             if (UserDecision != 1)
             {
                  Exit = true;
    break;
              }
    }
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the vowel stuff in a do-while loop. At the end of the loop, ask the user if they would like to continue.

```
do {
    // vowel work...

    System.out.println("Please press '1' to run the programme again\n"
              + "or any other number to exit.");
     userDecision = UserExit.nextInt();
} while(userDecision != -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'r looping logic is completely incorrect. You're going to print the number of vowels found on every character iteration and ask the user if they want to continue on each character iteration as well. Try this:

```
while(Exit == false) {
    for(int initial = 0; initial < Phrase2.length() && Exit == false; initial ++) {
      if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'a')
      {
          VowelCount++;
      }
      else if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'e')
      {
          VowelCount++;
      }
      else if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'i')
      {
          VowelCount++;
      }
      else if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'o')
      {
          VowelCount++;
      }
      else if (Phrase2.charAt(initial) == 'u')
      {
          VowelCount++;
      }
    }

    System.out.println("There are " +VowelCount+ " vowel(s) in your phrase. Please press '1' to run the programme again\n"
              + "or any other number to exit.");
      Choice = UserExit.nextLine();
       UserDecision = Integer.parseInt(Choice);
     if (UserDecision != 1) {
        Exit = true;
    }

}
```